# Do Fermi resonances show in Inelastic Neutron Scattering spectra?

Tags: spectroscopy, resonance

The Raman and FTIR spectra of a urea based mixture shows a strong Fermi resonance in the N-H stretching region, which difficults its interpretation. In an inelastic neutron scattering spectra of the same mixture, would the Fermi resonance be as obvious? Or not show at all?